# Can I set a default password for Active Directory entries? Or is there one already?

Tags: php, active-directory

I am adding users to Active Directory with PHP. I can add all the attributes I like, but not a password it seems, or unicdepwd for that matter. The thing is, my users don't need to specify a password as they are authenticated only on their email address, but the authentication server does require something in that field. I would hardcode the same one for everyone, but I can't seem to achieve that either.

So... Is it possible to set a default password for all new entries into a particular OU or CN on the AD server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of any mechanism in AD itself to let you specify a default password.

It's possible to set the password from PHP, but you need to enable SSL on the AD server first. Details can be found in this post:

[Change Password in Active Directory using LDAP/PHP/IIS/SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719082/change-password-in-active-directory-using-ldap-php-iis-ssl)