# Adding user via PHP:LDAP

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I have this code:

```
function makeUser() {
    $info['cn'] = "Test User";
    $info['sn'] = "User";
    $info['mail'] = "test@localhost";
    $info['objectclass'][0] = "Person";
    $info['objectclass'][1] = "User";

    $info['userpassword'] = "{MD5}".base64_encode(pack("H*",md5('Password1!')));
    $info['useraccountcontrol'] = 512;

    var_dump(ldap_add($this->connection, "CN=Test User,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=local", $info));
}
```

Which gives me this error:

> Warning: ldap_add() [function.ldap-add]: Add: Server is unwilling to perform

When I leave out the `$info['useraccountcontrol'] = 512;` part, It adds the account, but it is disabled..

I get this from the logging on both servers:

> Internal event: The LDAP server returned an error.
>
> Additional Data Error value: 0000052D: SvcErr: DSID-031A11E5, problem
>   5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0

I work on:

- Windows Server 2008 Active Directory (not R2) & Windows Server 2003
- PHP 5.3.5
- Normal LDAP connection, not LDAPS since I've given up on trying to get that work..

How can I get it like so, that the user is **not** disabled and does **not** have to change password when first logging in?

Comment: What does the LDAP server say in its logs about why it rejected your action?

Comment: Hmm, I can't seem to find the logs anywhere..

Comment: Now after enabling logging: problem 5003..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far Active-directory is concerned the password is not in 'userpassword' but in 'unicodePwd', you've got an example in [this other Stckoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5719082/608772). And I think that you need to use LDAPS.

Comment: It's indeed about using LDAPS, but setting up SSL was not a option. Figured a way around it by using the Windows `COM` function that sets the passwords and re-enables the account for me.

Comment: You can add an answer whith the COM solution. I think you will have success, because the question regulary come back.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem too (even connecting over LDAPS). When I did it in three steps (first add the account, then set the password, then enable the account), it worked.

It may be that you can combine the first two or last two steps, but I didn't test this.