# set password for new LDAP user

Tags: php, passwords, ldap

I've been trying to create windows user accounts out of PHP which itself is no problem. The only thing I can't do is to set the windows user password to the company standard password. 
I can create, change and delete the user account without any problems except for the password. Every time I create a user and try to log myself in with the credentials all I get is a "username or password wrong". And I checked the username.

What I tried so far:

- `ldapp_add` with clear password (`$ldaprecord['userPassword'] = "standard";`)
- `$ldaprecord['userPassword'] = '{MD5}' . base64_encode(pack('H*',md5($newuser_plaintext_password)));` like in the given example at [php.net](http://php.net/manual/de/function.ldap-add.php)
- tried to change password after adding the user see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719082/change-password-in-active-directory-using-ldap-php-iis-ssl)

It seems that I can change `$ldaprecord['userPassword']` but when I try to change `ldaprecord['unicodePwd']` the server is unwilling to do my request.
Which is the right one for the password?

I am not connecting to the AD via SSL. Is this my mistake? If so why can I delete user but not set their password?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Asked the sysadmin to establish a connection via SSL but he said the Lightweight Directory Services weren't even installed on the DC. In his opinion I'm working directly on the AD. Any thoughts on that?

Working on Windows 2012 R2 with IIS.

Comment: This is Active Directory and not OpenLDAP, correct? I see you referenced creating Windows user accounts anyway. If so, yes, an encrypted connection via SSL/TLS is required in order to change a password (unless you have modified AD to not require it, which would not be recommended). Also, typically (assuming again that this is AD...) you would use the `unicodePwd` attribute and not `userPassword`. The `userPassword` attribute doesn't work by default without some modification.

Comment: Yes it is an Active Directory. I will try to establish the LDAP connection via SSL. What bothers me is, that I can not change or set a password without SSL but I can delete users.

Comment: Yes, anytime you work with the password attribute it requires TLS or SSL. More than likely you should be doing a `ldap_start_tls($connection)` to encrypt if you're working with AD. You use that function directly after the `ldap_connect()` call, otherwise it wont work.

Comment: @ChadSikorra Tried that. "Unable to start TLS: Connect error". What do I have to do to get this running? Found some entries on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/de/function.ldap-start-tls.php)  but they didn't work for me. Running Windows 2012 with IIS here.

Comment: It could potentially be a certificate issue That's a common problem with LDAP and TLS in PHP. For a test (on the server where PHP is running) create the file (and folders if needed) `C:\OpenLDAP\sysconf\ldap.conf`. Then in that file add the line `TLS_REQCERT never`. That basically tells it not to validate the certificate from LDAP and just accept it. I can't remember if you would need to restart IIS after doing that or not.

Comment: No more errors from ldap_start_tls but back to `Server is unwilling to perform` from `ldap_add()`. Also tried to add `TLS_CACERT C:\OpenLDAP\sysconf\webcert.cer` to the ldap.conf and exported a AD-certificate (tried DER and Base-64 coded) but no change.

Comment: If it's not giving an error on the `ldap_start_tls()` then that's good. Now make sure you are using the `unicodePwd` attribute for the password (not `userPassword`). Also, when setting the `unicodePwd` value it needs to be in a special format. You can use the following to set the value properly: `$pasword = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-16LE", '"'.'PasswordGoesHere'.'"');`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First I did as @ChadSikorra told me to: I created the folder(s)/file `C:\OpenLDAP\sysconf\ldap.conf` and add the line `TLS_REQCERT never`. However this didn't help with `ldap_start_tls()` but our sysadmin checked the DC and found that the domain controller certificate wasn't installed. So I could finally establish a connection via `ldap_connect("ldaps://mydomaincontroller");` which means I could set the `unicodePwd`-attribute.

Next Problem was the encoding for the `unicodePwd`. This is the way to go:

```
$newPassword = "mypassword";
$newPassword = "\"" . $newPassword . "\"";
$newPass = mb_convert_encoding($newPassword, "UTF-16LE");
```

the strange thing is that it seems that you can not set the password when adding the user to the AD (correct me if there is a way). Instead you have to set the password afterwards:

```
$result = ldap_add(...);
$entry = array(
    "unicodePwd" => "$newPass",
    "pwdLastSet" => 0
);
ldap_modify($connect, $member, $entry);
```

Setting the password with `ldap_add()` didn't work for me. `pwdLastSet` is forcing the user to change the password after login and `$member` is the "ID" of the user (e.g.: `CN=johndoe, ou=person, dc=mycompany`). Make sure to 
use a unique key after the "CN=".

Thank you guys for your help.

Comment: Some more info about the `unicodePwd` attribute (it may help someone). Yes it can't be set on user creation.
http://www.letu.edu/people/markroedel/netcccu/activedirectorypasswordchanges.htm

Comment: Nice, this is the only way to create unicodepwd that actually work me at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Microsoft article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/034a0e33-a8ab-474e-ba6c-3371724d0be1/forum-faq-how-is-user-password-of-user-objects-stored-in-active-directory-can-i-view-it-can-i?forum=winserverDS) it looks as though the password is stored in a field **unicodePwd** which can only be set but not read. And apart from that the NTLM-Hash and the NT-Hash can be stored in the SAM-Database (which is AFAIK not accessible through LDAP) so you won't have much luck in changing the password via LDAP.

There is an article though on how to change a Windows200-Password via LDAP referenced on the website stated above.

Comment: While this should pretty much always be the case, it should be noted that it is possible to set the password using the RFC standard `userPassword` attribute in AD. However, you do need to go out of your way to enable it. Some additional info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223249.aspx

Comment: Ooi: Which RFC are you referring to?

Comment: RFC 4519, which describes a standard LDAP schema.I think that's the most current RFC for that anyway? The LDAP related RFCs aren't exactly page turners for reading (:

Comment: That RFC specifies technical specifications on attributes "widely used" but doesn't imply that those attributes have to be used. It (sadly) is up to the Directory-admin to specify which attributes are actually used :(

Comment: True, good point. I never even noticed the footnote regarding how the password is stored in RFC 4513: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4513#appendix-B.2.5 . Learn something new every day.